# How to create a list of weeks/months/quarters between a range of two dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Based on a date range, I am trying to create four lists of strings with weeks, months, quarters, and year that are formated in a specific way.

The below code is working fine (please note the special way of calculating the weeks. That is intended).

My problem is that the implementation fails as soon as the dateEnd is defined to be in the following year (eg 03-28-2019). Then, the generated lists become incomplete/incorrect.

Is there a better approach to achieve the goal?

Here is a fiddle... https://jsbin.com/wipehahigo/1/edit?html,js,console

```
dateStart = "01-01-2018";
dateEnd = "03-28-2018";

//get list of week strings   
lowerRange = Math.ceil(moment(dateStart, "MM-DD-YYYY").dayOfYear()/7);
upperRange = Math.ceil(moment(dateEnd, "MM-DD-YYYY").dayOfYear()/7);
year = moment(dateStart, "MM-DD-YYYY").year();
weekList = []
for (var i = lowerRange; i <= upperRange; i++) {
  weekList.push('W' + i + '_' + year);
}



//get list of month strings    
lowerRange = moment(dateStart, "MM-DD-YYYY").month()+1;
upperRange = moment(dateEnd, "MM-DD-YYYY").month()+1;
year = moment(dateStart, "MM-DD-YYYY").year();
monthList = []
for (var i = lowerRange; i <= upperRange; i++) {
  monthList.push('M' + i + '_' + year);
}




//get list of quarter strings
lowerRange = moment(dateStart, "MM-DD-YYYY").quarter();
upperRange = moment(dateEnd, "MM-DD-YYYY").quarter();
year = moment(dateStart, "MM-DD-YYYY").year();
quarterList = []
for (var i = lowerRange; i <= upperRange; i++) {
  quarterList.push('Q' + i + '_' + year);
}




//get list of year strings
lowerRange = moment(dateStart, "MM-DD-YYYY").year();
upperRange = moment(dateEnd, "MM-DD-YYYY").year();
yearList = []
for (var i = lowerRange; i <= upperRange; i++) {
  yearList.push('Y' + i + '_' + year);
}



console.log(weekList);
console.log(monthList);
console.log(quarterList);
console.log(yearList);
```

**Update and Solution**

I doing this now... https://jsbin.com/mepifevico/1/edit?html,js,console

```
window['moment-range'].extendMoment(moment);

weekList = [];
monthList = [];
quarterList = [];
yearList = [];

dateStart = "01-01-2018";
dateEnd = "03-28-2019";

dateStart = moment(dateStart, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
dateEnd   = moment(dateEnd, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
dateRange = moment.range(dateStart, dateEnd);

for (let d of dateRange.by('week')) {
  weekNumber = Math.ceil(d.dayOfYear()/7);
  year = d.year();
  weekList.push('W' + weekNumber + '_' + year);
}



for (let d of dateRange.by('month')) {
  monthNumber = d.month() + 1;
  year = d.year();
  monthList.push('M' + monthNumber + '_' + year);
}


for (let d of dateRange.by('quarter')) {
  quarterNumber = d.quarter();
  year = d.year();
  quarterList.push('Q' + quarterNumber + '_' + year);
}

for (let d of dateRange.by('year')) {
  yearNumber = d.year();
  year = d.year();
  yearList.push('Y' + yearNumber + '_' + year);
}



console.log(weekList)

console.log(monthList)

console.log(quarterList)

console.log(yearList)
```

Comment: Except for the last function, you are only getting the days / weeks / months of the last year you entered. Take a look at this: https://jsbin.com/kuzawufeso/edit?html,js,console A solution would be to combine your last functions with the other 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your calculations work across multiple years, you should base them not on the endDate, but on the **duration between the two dates**. To do so, you can make your for loops going from the startDate to the startDate + duration.

I made an example for the calculation of the weeks : https://jsbin.com/xejocusana/edit?html,js,console

```
dateStart = "01-01-2018";
dateEnd = "03-31-2019";

start = moment(dateStart, "MM-DD-YYYY")
end = moment(dateEnd, "MM-DD-YYYY")

lowerRange = Math.floor(moment(dateStart, "MM-DD-YYYY").dayOfYear()/7);
// calculate the number of weeks between the two dates
numberOfWeeks = end.diff(start, 'weeks');
year = moment(dateStart, "MM-DD-YYYY").year();

weekListA = []
for (var i = lowerRange; i <= lowerRange + numberOfWeeks; i++) {
  weekListA.push('W' + (i%52 +1) + '_' + (year+ Math.floor(i/52)));
}
console.log(weekListA);
```

I added :

- a calculation of the `numberOfWeeks`, needed for the limit of the loop ;
- a modulo `+ (i%52 +1)` in the loop, to have the number of the week (You have to write +1 to make it begin at 0. Due to this constraint, you have to use Math.floor() instead of Math.ceil() when you calculate lowerRange) ;
- a `+ Math.floor(i/52)` in the loop, to increment the number of the year ;

I let you check if all the cases are covered (dates across more than 2 years, dates included or excluded, etc.)

Comment: I am accepting this answer since it really solves the problem. Thx. However I came up with another solution. See my update in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's just for the weekList but you should be able to figured it out for the rest :

```
lowerRange = moment(dateStart, "MM-DD-YYYY").week();
upperRange = moment(dateEnd, "MM-DD-YYYY").week();
year = moment(dateStart, "MM-DD-YYYY").year();
year2 = moment(dateEnd, "MM-DD-YYYY").year();

//add extra weeks to upperRange if the date range > 12 months
upperRange += (year2-year)*52-lowerRange;

weekList = []
for (var i = lowerRange; i <= upperRange; i++) {
  //some fix to show the year
  weekList.push('W' + (i-lowerRange) + '_' + (year+Math.floor((i-lowerRange)/12)));
}
```

Comment: it seems that week() returns the calendar week. I need the week to always start on jan 1 each year.